# detecting webgl capabilities of the client

Tags: webgl

How can I guess what kind of a machine i'm dealing with when running webgl?

Could I query something like `MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTES`, `OES_texture_float` and other such properties and guess if it's a more high end or lower end GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way would be looking at user agent string (`navigator.userAgent`), `WEBGL_UNMASKED_VENDOR` and `WEBGL_UNMASKED_RENDERER` from `WEBGL_debug_renderer_info` to try to figure out user's platform (mobile or desktop) and GPU (from `WEBGL_UNMASKED_RENDERER`).

E.g., here's my UA and renderer name:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30
Intel Iris OpenGL Engine
```

From that you can guess that I'm running a desktop Mac (`Intel Mac` part of UA) that has Intel iGPU (from renderer).

Another example, from an iPhone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1
Apple A9 GPU
```

From that you obviously can detect, that you're dealing with an iPhone 6S (since it has A9 chip).

Similarly you can detect Androids and WinPhones and query GPUs.

Comment: many thanks for the answer, for some reason i missed this notification

Comment: for further details you can check the script behind webglreport.com, at https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/webglreport